# Where can I find alias names for core 14 PDF fonts?

Tags: ios, pdf, fonts

I have implemented a PDF reader on iOS. One of my users sent me a file for which text extraction was not working, and it turns out that it refers to a BaseFont of name "CourierNew", which is not one of the standard "base 14 fonts" required by the PDF spec; but some software (e.g. iBooks by Apple) knows to treat it as an alias of Courier.

Can anyone point me to a canonical list of such aliases, or is it just something you learn by experience and keep adding special cases?

Comment: Certainly no one could have a list of all fonts and which one you should choose. The Base 14 fonts are:

Helvetica, Helvetica Bold, Helvetica Oblique, Helvetica Bold Oblique (any sans serif font)
Times, Times Bold, Times Italic, Times Bold Italic (any serif font)
Courier, Courier Bold, Courier Oblique, Courier Bold Oblique (any fixed pitch font)
Symbol
ZapfDingbats

Comment: PDF file can refer to external fonts, font usage is not limited by 14 core fonts. And this is your case probably, for example you can perfectly fine find CourierNew in X:\windows\fonts.

Comment: Kevin: certainly no-one could have a list of all ways in which PDF files could deviate from the standard, but what I was wondering is whether there's supplementary part of the standard (which is what Mark Stephens pointed me to below).

Comment: Hugh: It seems likely the software used to author the PDF in question made the same assumption as you: that everyone is using Windows (but see the "P" in "PDF"!) AFAIUI, standards-compliant PDF cannot refer to external fonts in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in the PDF reference guide. You will also find others turning up such as ArialMT and TimesNewRomanPS

Comment: In the PDF reference guide I'm looking at, "CourierNew" is not listed as an alias of "Courier", but "CourierCourierNew" is! Anyway, that's a helpful list, thank you.